# Is process in an infinite loop?

Tags: c, process

How can I check if a process is in an infinite loop ?
how the scheduler will come to high priority process that is waiting ?

Its a question I gon in a job interview ...

thanks

Comment: Put an output statement in the loop?

Comment: These are two separate questions...

Answer (score 3):

It was proven in 1936 that it is impossible in general to check if a process is in an infinite loop. That is a trick question.

The other question has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: *It was proven in 1936 that it is impossible to check if a process is in an infinite loop*: a reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Alan Turing, "On Computable Numbers, with an Application to the Entscheidungsproblem"